# How to use 2 objects in an ArrayAdapter for an Android List?

Tags: java, android

I have a list of Bookings: `List<Booking> bookings`
and a list of Persons: `List<Person> persons`

I want to create a single `arrayAdapter` that uses data from both lists.

**BookingAdapter**:

```
public class BookingAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Booking> {

    public ReviewBookingReferenceResultAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Booking> objects) {
        super(context, resource, (List<Booking>) objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Booking current = getItem(position);
```

Would I have to create a `custom Object` to hold data of both `Person` and `Booking`. Loop through the objects and create the lsit and pass it to this Adapter?

Or is there another method?

Comment: are you making a listview or expandable_listview?

Comment: @PankajNimgade A `ListFragment`

Comment: make List<Person> persons instance variable of List<Booking> bookings

Comment: for ArrayAdapter pass you array as List<Object>. In Adapter constructor use one more param as objectType , which tells whether you are sending Booking/Person type, according this type inflater ur views (if view varies). 1. Adapter Class  `extends ArrayAdapter<Object>` 2.Constructor  `public MyAdapter(Context context,int resource, List<Object> objects,int objectType)`.. Hope this might help..

Comment: can you explain what you want to get on the screen?

Comment: @MIlošKresović I have 2 list of objects, one containing data about booking and one about person. I want the `ArrayAdapter` to show data from both booking and person

Comment: @StevieG understand that, but how exactly you want to show both data?

Comment: @MIlošKresović with an `ArrayAdapter` and a `ListFragment`

Comment: I thought visually. If it is list of Bookings, you should have Person associated with it and get it from there.